# Editing and inserting new attributes into XML files based on value of existing attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file structured like this:
All examples I have read shows inserting node but not as described below.

```
<asset>
         <vehicle inUse="true">
            <type>sedan</type>
            <model>735i</model>
            <make>BMW</make>
            <year>2017</year>
          </vehicle>

         <vehicle inUse="true">
            <type>sedan</type>
            <model>735i</model>
            <make>BMW</make>
            <year>2016</year>
          </vehicle>
</asset>
```

I would like to do a batch edit and insert a new vehicle node after an existing vehicle node with the highest year value. So after 2017

For example the code above will end up like this:

```
<asset>
         <vehicle inUse="true">
            <type>sedan</type>
            <model>735i</model>
            <make>BMW</make>
            <year>2017</year>
          </vehicle>

<!-- new node here-->

         <vehicle inUse="true">
            <type>sedan</type>
            <model>735i</model>
            <make>BMW</make>
            <year>2010</year>
          </vehicle>

         <vehicle inUse="true">
            <type>sedan</type>
            <model>735i</model>
            <make>BMW</make>
            <year>2016</year>
          </vehicle>
</asset>
```

Comment: Did you tried something? What is the actual problem? Where you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the xml into xmlString and you should search where is the highest year value, get it's index

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var vehicles= root.Descendants("vehicle").ToArray();
var elementBeforeInsert = vehicles[index+1];
elementBeforeInsert.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("vehicle")); // insert your vehicle here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var maxYear = xml.Elements().Max(e => (int)e.Element("year"));
var newestVehicle = xml.Elements().First(e => (int)e.Element("year") == maxYear);
newestVehicle.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("vehicle"));
```

This code is not very efficient because it does two passes over xml.

If you connect the MoreLinq library, the code becomes even easier:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var newestVehicle = xml.Elements().MaxBy(e => (int)e.Element("year")).First();
newestVehicle.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("vehicle"));
```

Comment: _.. two passes over xml_ - not over xml, but over in-memory information about loaded xml ;)